# Why do these two C++ examples involving a protected derived class compile differently?

Tags: c++

According to my understanding, a derived class is able to convert a derived class pointer to the base class pointer even though there is protected inheritance.

Why is this code wrong under the vs2017, generating a compiler error?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "base"; }
};

class deri : protected base {
public:
    void f() override { cout << "derived"; }
    void test(base* bp) { bp->f(); }  
};



int main()
{
    deri d, d2;
    d.test(&d);   //error,conversion to inaccessible base class "base" is not allowed
}
```

I rewrite the code like this and it compiles successfully：

```
class deri : protected base {
public:
    void f() override { cout << "derived"; }
    void test(deri* dp) { base*bp=dp;bp->f(); }  
};


int main()
{
    deri d, d2;
    d.test(&d);   //it's Ok,and prints derived.
}
```

In my opinion,these two codes just do the same thing,convert a deri pointer to
a base pointer,and I'm comfused.Can anyone tell me the difference between these two codes?

Comment: You have used protected inheritance. Lets start with why did you do that? What do you think this gains for you?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox this is just a test,protected inheritance maybe doesn't make much sense, but it's the same result with private inheritance as the default inheritance for the class.

Answer (score 7):

> In my opinion,these two codes just do the same thing,convert a deri pointer to a base pointer

But they don't do it at the same place. In the first version, it is the scope of `main` where the conversion must happen. But `main` cannot access `base` in order to do the conversion, for `main` is completely outside the scope of `deri`, where such a conversion is allowed.

And that's what access control is about, for a class to tell at which scope is the name of its member (or base) is accessible. Even if your two pieces of code (assuming we ignore the fact one doesn't even compile) would result in the exact same thing happening, there are still rules in place for encapsulation that the compiler must abide by.

So you can either make that `base` public, or work with the limitations of protected accessibility. As an aside though, `protected` bases are very rarely seen in the wild. I suggest you ponder whether or not you even need it.

Comment: Maybe also add that protected inheritance is very rarely the correct type of inheritance to use. I doubt it is correct in this example ...

Comment: thanks your anwser, I already understand it. In the fact, I write deri with class default inheritance method (private inheritance) at the beginning,then I change to the protected just out of curiosity.

Comment: Not that clear for me. in the first example ``f()`` is public in ``Base`` inherited as private and overridden as  ``public`` how the conversion is inaccessible?

Comment: @SoulimaneMammar - The conversion is on the argument of `test`. In the first example it necessitates `deri*` -> `base*` in the scope of main.

Comment: Because it's inherited from with the `protected` access specifier.

Comment: When type conversion between derived and base what exactly happens (in terms of calls)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Let's assume the compiler authorizes the conversion from `deri*` to `base*`, the newly obtained pointer will be useless in the scope of `main`!! why? here is why:

the `class deri: protected base` statement means that:

1. `private` members in `base` are not accessible in `deri`
2. `protected` members in `base` will be `protected` in `deri`
3. `public` members in `base` will be `protected` in `deri`

So in `main` scope the supposedly converted pointer will have no access to the `base` part of `d` so why do the conversion in the first place (and this why the compiler doesn't accept these kind of conversions)

In the second example there is no conversion taking place in the `main` scope and in the definition of the `test` member function the conversion is possible. Why? for the same reasons as before (the converted variable `bp` is defined inside the `deri` scope and hence has access to the `public` and `protected` `base` part members of the object pointed by `dp`